# Proxy 302 redirection could not catch in jquery ajax

Tags: jquery, redirect, http-status-code-302

This is my ajax snippet

```
$.ajax({
  url: url,
  type: "POST",
  success: function(response, statusText, xhr) {
    if (xhr.status == 302 || xhr.status == 0) {
  window.location = xhr.getResponseHeader("Location");
      window.location.reload();
}
    else {
  success();
}
  },
  error: function (xhr) {
    if (xhr.status == 302 || xhr.status == 0 || (xhr.getResponseHeader("Content-Type").indexOf("text/html") == 0)) {
      window.location = xhr.getResponseHeader("Location");
      window.location.reload();
    }
  }
});
```

I want to reload the whole page when the server returns a 302 Code.

The above snippet is working well and fine when i directly access the Application Server (WebSphere in my case)

But when accessing the same with a Web Server, the web server is taking the 302 request returned from the application server and redirecting and sending the login page content as response. So the part of the page is getting updated with the login page content.

I want to reload my page in this case of a Web Server. The ajax is getting a status code of 200.